# Turn off Database Navigator suggestions that my sql is bad

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

I'm using this plugin for intelliJ

[Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator)

I just wanted a simple tool to check my sqlite database, now that the firefox plugin I use is no longer working with the latest firefox update.

Sad!

Anyway, the plugin is good... except it seems to have added it's own "clever" sql checker, that finds all the sql in my java files, and then tells me if there are problems with the sql.

All well and good, but this

- slows down editing those java files
- doesn't work, finding phantom errors
- isn't needed. Who struggles with writing sql?

So right now I have a bunch of red "tick" marks down the side of any java file with sql in it, as the plugin imagines up issues where there are none. I'd like these to just go away, I don't need code telling me if my code works - any ideas 
how?

Here is an example of this thing:
[image]

I don't want the sql "string" to be treated as special, I don't want "analysis" performed on it, I can write working SQL.

Every time i load this class, the ... whatever it is takes up time looking at all the strings, and then makes EVERYTHING red on the sidebar. I don't want to disable *all* inspections on this page, as I do like to see when my java code has an error.

I know it is possible to tell intellij to stop looking at strings, I had this setting before - and then my laptop was stolen, thank you thieves - and now I have setup my environment again, I don't have my notes on how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to show the issue?

Comment: @TarunLalwani yep

Comment: Please check the answer posted by Juan, if it doesn't work, let me know and I will take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings are "analyzed" when they are used in some methods of the package java.sql.

- Click on a string and press Alt+Enter to expand the suggestion list

[image]

- Select "Language Injection Settings" to open the configuration dialog for "SQL"

[image]

- Uncheck all the checkboxes, press "OK" and all errors must be gone

Technical note: Settings are stored in `<USER>/<.IDE_VERSION>/config/options/IntelliLang.xml`